# Style lags for several seconds in React app in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, reactjs, internet-explorer-11, redux

I'm working on a large React/Redux app. It has no problem rendering in chrome & firefox, but just recently I've found that some styles simply don't render properly for 1-5 seconds (or sometimes at all) for several elements after a large repaint of a region (selecting a new tabbed view). The CSS is all pre-loaded so it's not waiting on CSS to load.

The area that's causing the problem is a 'gallery' view that shows 50 items at a time, w/ thumbnails if they exist, rendered w/ `collection.map(renderItem)`. If I **remove** the call to render the individual items and just render the area, the styles load properly (it's mostly the region headers that are not getting styled). Once I replace the items, the region header styles don't get displayed until after all the individual items are done loading. Also, on first load of the items the style takes a second to show up, but if I then switch to a different view and then back to the gallery view again, the header shows up unstyled and when you select it in the Inspector, no highlighting appears on the page, as if the unstyled element isn't connected to the dom tree element.

I was thinking of trying to do some progressive rendering but even if I load just one or two of the items at a time the styles break.

Can anyone help figure out why the styles don't render properly?

Comment: I was able to get around this problem by changing my gallery from display: flex to float: left.

Comment: Well, then you probably had some magic polyfill for flexbox that was enabled for IE. And it took some time to make the layout using Javascript. So you probably should avoid using such flexbox-with-polyfill solution for critical components.